# how to dynamically change chrome extension icon

Tags: javascript, dynamic, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension. The scenario is kind of

When i click on the icon extension send POST request to server and on basis of the GET response it procceds on any of 3 different if/else if/ else statement. I am using page action to show the icon next to address bar. 
I want my extension icon to change dynamically on each if/else  if /else statement.

this is my backgound.js to make the icon visible next to address bar.

```
    chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          })
        ],
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ]);
```

});
});

this is my manifest.json

```
"page_action" :
{
"default_icon" : "icon-191.png",
"default_title" : "xxx",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
```

},

Any suggestion how can i change extension toolber icon dynamically on diffetent statement?
Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, [it's there in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-SetIcon).

`declarativeContent` API can only execute a very limited number of *actions* instead of arbitrary code.

Thankfully for you, `chrome.declarativeContent.setIcon` is an action that does exactly what you need. Use it just like the one you're using already, except it expects a parameter.

And give that docs page a read in general.

Comment: i have the answer now.                                       chrome.pageAction.setIcon({tabId: tab.id, path: 'x.png'});
      i put this line on my get/post success method